# Parse-server result.attributes vs get()

Tags: parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

Been using Parse Server for about a month in our project, and it's been a fantastic addition to our tech stack. However, there is one thing that has slowed down our team a bit ; when using `Parse.Query`, we can only access the fields of the returned Object by using `get('fieldName')`, which seems to be very redundant and prone to errors (using strings to get the fields). In Firebase, there is a method to get all the data : `.data()`. I haven't seen this feature in Parse.

We found out about a property when getting the query result called `attributes`. It seems to be an object that we can destructure and directly get all the  fields of the Parse Object. For example :

```
const query = Parse.Query('Movie');
const result = await query.first();
const { title, price } = result.attributes
```

There is only a slight reference to it in the docs : https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Object.html under `Members`, only with the description `Prototype getters/setters`.

If this property makes it much more easier/convenient than the `get()` method, is there any reason it is not include in the get started guide of Parse-SDK-JS? Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this line](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/ParseObject.js#L595), the get method just access the attributes property and returns the value for the specified key, so you should be fine with `const { title, price } = result.attributes`.

Comment: Thanks Davi! That's what I thought. I created a Pull Request to add it to the docs